# Get Token request returned http error: 401 and server response: Invalid client secret is provided

Tags: azure, serverless, azure-function-app, azure-deployment

I sometime got this error while deploying function app to Azure.

> Error: Get Token request returned http error: 401 and server response:
> {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS7000215: Invalid
> client secret is provided.\r\nTrace ID

Comment: Deploying from where?  Visual Studio? Azure DevOps?

Comment: Using `serverless deploy` for deployment

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan :Try to regenerate a client secret: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPREn.png

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your problem:

[image]

The reason for the error is that you have used an invalid client secret, and you need to regenerate a client secret.

[image]

Comment: Did it solve the problem? Because in my case it did not.